# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError using RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java

I have to do a recursive HTTP request every half second, until the result is "completed" or "faulted", and I'm doing it this way

```
Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Long aLong) {
                        return CimaComm.getInstance().getService().getPaymentStatus();
                    }
                }).takeUntil(new Func1<Object, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Object o) {
                CimaPaymentStatusResponse responseState = (CimaPaymentStatusResponse) o;
                return responseState.status == CimaStatusEnum.completed || responseState.status == CimaStatusEnum.faulted;
            }
        }).subscribe(this::onPaymentPollingUpdate, this::handleCimaError);
```

the problem that I am facing is this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at rx.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:107)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.start(Http2Connection.java:521)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection.start(Http2Connection.java:505)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.startHttp2(RealConnection.java:298)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:287)
09-06 09:33:12.867 E/AndroidRuntime( 1300):     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)

...
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'recursive HTTP request every half second,'? Polling ?

Comment: @Blackbelt  yes that

Comment: I can't really be sure it's this, but `interval` by default uses the `computation` scheduler which is bounded to the number of available CPUs. In other words, it might be that the HTTP calls take too long and the computation scheduler simply cannot allocate more threads... that's a rough read from the stack trace. Could you try `Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())` instead pls? In any case you are doing io operations - network calls. If that solves it I'm happy to post a more details explanation.